# How can I store a 64-bit memory address in a variable?

Tags: c, pointers

I need to store a 64-bit memory address in a variable, a `long` should be large enough to hold such value.

For example:

```
long arr[2];

//store the memory address of arr[1] in arr[0]
arr[0] = (long)(arr + 1);

printf("arr[0]: 0x%012x Actual address: %p\n", arr[0], (void *)arr);
```

Output:

```
arr[0]: 0x00007c6a2c20, Actual address: 0x7ffe7c6a2c20
```

The value stored in `arr[0]` seems to be truncated.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hard to tell. `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32-bit. Use `long long` to be sure you have a big enough integer (or, of course, use a data type that is meant for pointers, as Sourav Ghosh says.)

Comment: @Amadan Unfortunately due to architecture constrains I am unable to use proper pointer types. Not easily anyway. For this particular case, the architecture is more or less set in stone, so portability of the code is not essential. long is guaranteed to be 8 bytes in size.

Comment: `%x` should be `%lx` so I'm voting to close as simple typo. But you shouldn't use long in the first place, use `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that `%x` [expects an `unsigned int`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), but on your particular implementation an address appears to be an `unsigned long`, so use `%lx` instead.

Note that technically this is undefined behaviour, so always use `%p` in production code as depending on architecture the underlying size of a pointer may change.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to store a 64 bit values, you can use `uint64_t` type of variable.

However, since the values you want to store are addresses, probably you need to use `uintptr_t`, make sure the available size of that type in your platform and you can use that.

Comment: Unfortunately due to architecture constrains I am unable to use proper pointer types. Not easily anyway. Your response does propose proper practices, for those reading this answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 64 bit machine, you can use pointer to that value_type it is pointing to. Knowing value type will help you in choosing correct pointer and operations can be performed on pointer.